# Nexus 4 screenshot not viewable on PC

Tags: nexus-4, screenshots

I made some screenshots with my Nexus 4. On the phone, I can open them, and they are all viewable. I edited some of them on the phone. When I copy them to a Windows 7 PC, they are all 0 bytes big and not viewable. Is this a bug?

Comment: It sounds as if the files haven't transferred properly? How have you transferred the files? Have you copied the correct files?

Comment: It seems to be a bug. I noticed if i take a screen shoot and don't edit it i can copy them to the PC without problems. But as soon as i edit them on the smartphone Win7 says they are 0 bytes big (they are still on the phone and are stil viewable on the phone)